# django passing variable to javascript in html template

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I was trying to pass a variable to my html template in my django project and I can't seem to find a solution to why it doesn't work.

The input of username_list: ['name1', 'name2']

back end:

```
    username_list = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]

    return render(response, "main/main-page.html", {"list": username_list})
```

template:

```
<script>
    let availableKeywords = {{ list }};
    console.log(availableKeywords);
</script>
```

The javascript won't run and I don't understand if there is another correct way of doing it that I am not aware of.
Can't figure it out.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The most secure way will be to use the [**`|json_script`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-json_script):

```
{{ list|json_script:'my_list' }}
```

and then process this with:

```
<script>
    const list = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('my_list').textContent);
    console.log(list);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your code works as expected, you should use the json_script template tag to serialize your data properly.

```
username_list = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]
# Serialize the list as a JSON string
username_list_json = json.dumps(username_list)

return render(request, "main/main-page.html", {"username_list_json": 
username_list_json})
```

Template (main-page.html):

```
 <script>
    var availableKeywords = JSON.parse('{{ username_list_json|escapejs }}');
    console.log(availableKeywords);
</script>
```

- use the json.dumps() method to serialize the username_list as a JSON
  string in the backend.
- use the {{ username_list_json|escapejs }}
  filter to escape and properly format the JSON string for inclusion in
  JavaScript.
- parse the JSON string in JavaScript using JSON.parse()
  to convert it into a JavaScript array.